# What is a realistic model for simulating physical tampering of a channel? (ex: nearby vibrations)

Tags: quantum-gate, simulation, teleportation, depolarizing-channel

Somewhat related to [this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15425/simulate-a-quantum-channel-with-a-certain-fidelity).

Imagine a fully functioning quantum network, where qubits are transported via fiber optic cable. If vibrations were to physically tamper with a channel in such a network, what would be a realistic representation of such tampering?

I know that quantum systems are very sensitive to nearby physical disturbances... I imagine something like drilling a jack hammer close to a fiber optic cable carrying qubits from Alice to Bob would cause serious disturbances to all the qubits. If I recall correctly, current advancements in hardware are prone to serious disturbances from something a lot less intrusive than vibrations from a jack hammer.

I am trying to characterize effects from adversaries physically tampering with a channel and/or natural occurrences (such as earth quakes).