# How to calculate the average fidelity of Pauli error channel

Tags: qiskit, quantum-state, noise, fidelity

This question is related to [this](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15425/simulate-a-quantum-channel-with-a-certain-fidelity) and [this](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/16074/how-to-calculate-the-average-fidelity-of-an-amplitude-damping-channel).

I am working on Qiskit to design QEC schemes.

My model works with Pauli errors.

I would like to give to my Pauli error channel probabilities $p_x,p_y,p_z$ corresponding to a fidelity $F$.

I could find [here](https://algassert.com/post/2001) a way to map a depolarizing channel $\mathcal{D}_{\lambda}$, to its equivalent Pauli channel $\mathcal{P}_{p_x,p_y,p_z}$ with $p_x=p_y=p_z$.
Hence, for this case, the [first question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15425/simulate-a-quantum-channel-with-a-certain-fidelity) would be enough.

However, I may need to customise the probabilities.

Stemming from the related questions, I need to solve the following equation:

$$\bar{F}(\mathcal{P}_{p_x,p_y,p_z}) = \int \langle\varphi|\mathcal{P}_{p_x,p_y,p_z}(|\varphi\rangle\langle\varphi|)|\varphi\rangle\ d\varphi$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Two steps. First, we find the *entanglement* fidelity $F_e(\mathcal{P}_{p_x,p_y,p_z})=1-(p_x+p_y+p_z)$. Next, we use Horodecki's formula that connects the average and entanglement fidelities

$$
\overline{F}(\mathcal{E})=\frac{NF_e(\mathcal{E})+1}{N+1}\tag1
$$

to get

$$
\overline{F}(\mathcal{E})=1-\frac23(p_x+p_y+p_z).\tag2
$$

There is also an alternative approach that exploits the fact that Pauli eigenstates form a spherical 3-design.

### Entanglement fidelity

There are many ways to quickly find the entanglement fidelity $F_e(\mathcal{E})$ of a channel $\mathcal{E}$. For example, it can be shown directly from the definition that $F_e(\mathcal{E})$ can be read off of the channel's Pauli transfer matrix (aka process matrix) $\chi(\mathcal{E})$. Namely, $F_e(\mathcal{E})$ is the diagonal element corresponding to the identity. In the present case, we have $\chi(\mathcal{P}_{p_x,p_y,p_z})=\mathrm{diag}(1-(p_x+p_y+p_z), p_x, p_y, p_z)$, so $F_e(\mathcal{P}_{p_x,p_y,p_z})=1-(p_x+p_y+p_z)$.

Alternatively, we can use the formula for $F_e(\mathcal{E})$ in terms of the channel's Kraus operators

$$
F_e(\mathcal{E})=\frac{1}{N^2}\sum_i|\mathrm{tr}K_i|^2\tag4
$$

c.f. equation $(9.135)$ on page $421$ in Nielsen & Chuang. For a Pauli channel all but one operators in $(4)$ have zero trace and once again we obtain $F_e(\mathcal{P}_{p_x,p_y,p_z})=1-(p_x+p_y+p_z)$.

### Horodecki's formula

You can find a beautiful proof of formula $(1)$ in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9807091). The key fact established in the course of the proof is that twirling$^1$ any channel produces a depolarizing channel with the same entanglement fidelity as the original channel.

You can also find a more technical but shorter proof of $(1)$ in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0205035).

### Spherical 2-designs

Alternatively, we can use a spherical 2-design to simplify the evaluation of the integral

$$
\overline{F}(\mathcal{P}_{p_x,p_y,p_z})=\int\langle\psi|\mathcal{P}_{p_x,p_y,p_z}(|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|)|\psi\rangle d\psi.\tag5
$$

Tetrahedron is the smallest spherical 2-design, but it is also not the most convenient to work with in this context. Instead, we can use an octahedron which is the smallest spherical 3-design. See [this paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82807243.pdf). This is convenient because the eigenstates of the Pauli operators form an octahedron. We get

$$
\overline{F}(\mathcal{P}_{p_x,p_y,p_z})=\frac{1}{|S|}\sum_{|\psi\rangle\in S}\langle\psi|\mathcal{P}_{p_x,p_y,p_z}(|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|)|\psi\rangle\tag6
$$

where $S=\{|0\rangle, |1\rangle, |+\rangle, |-\rangle, |{+i}\rangle, |{-i}\rangle\}$. We then calculate

$$
\begin{align}
\overline{F}(\mathcal{P}_{p_x,p_y,p_z})&=\frac{1}{6}\left(6\cdot(1-(p_x+p_y+p_z)+2p_x+2p_y+2p_z\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{6}\left(6-4(p_x+p_y+p_z)\right)\\
&=1-\frac23(p_x+p_y+p_z)\tag7
\end{align}
$$

in agreement with $(2)$.

---

<sup>$^1$ Twirl takes a channel and produces another channel by averaging the effect of the conjugation of the input channel by a Haar-random unitary.</sup>